# PowerShell Compare-Object Does Not Accept 2 Files as Arguments then Compares Them

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell scripts that turns the following into a script that accepts 2 files as command line arguments, then outputs the difference of the two files to a text file.

Currently, my worthless code is as follows:

```
# Compare two text files passed as command line arguments

Function compareFiles()
{
    Param (
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$file1,
    [string]$file2 
    )
    $file1 = resolve-path \.$file1
    $file2 = resolve-path \.$file2
    if ($file1 -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "No source file."
    }
    if ($file2 -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "No comparison file."
    }

    # Compare the two file objects
    # => means $file2 has that line but not $file1
    # =< means $file1 has that line but not $file2
    # to see lines that arw the same, add -includeequal to end of the following line
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $file1) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $file2) | Out-File "$file1_$file2_Compare.txt" -Force
}
```

In a PowerShell console, the line `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $obj1) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $obj2` works fine after defining `$obj1="test1.txt"` and `$obj2="test2.txt"`.

When I run `.\Compare-Files.ps1 -file1 test1.txt -file2 test2.txt` from a PowerShell console, I get the following:

```
compareFiles : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'file1' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Users\debug255\Documents\Fiverr\PowerShell\Orders\armytra1n3d\FO4ADB39A404\Compare-Files.ps1:27 char:21
+ compareFiles -file1 $file1 -file2 $file2 | Out-File "$file1_$file2_Co ...
+                     ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [compareFiles], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,compareFiles
```

**This error was resolved by removing the leftover `$obj1` and `$obj2` variables from earlier testing**

This script from Hey Scripting Guy works fine

```
$fileA = "test1.txt"
$fileB = "test2.txt"

if(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $fileA) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $fileB))
{
    "files are different"
}
Else
{
    "Files are the same"
}
```

`test1.txt` contains the following:

```
test1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
asaskjdahs
sl kasldk
```

test2.txt contains:

```
test2
1
23
3
4
5
6
799
asaskjdahs
sl kasldkJ
```

I am using PowerShell 5.1.14393.1066 on Windows 10.

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT**

I changed the script entirely so that there is no function for the comparison, and I used an example I found on GitHub for opening and comparing MS Word documents, which helped significantly.

```
# Compare two text files passed as command line arguments

Param (
[Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    $file1,
    $file2
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Remove read-only attributes from baseFile
$baseFile = Get-ChildItem $file1
if ($baseFile.IsReadOnly) {
    $baseFile.IsReadOnly = $false
}

try {
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $file1) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $file2) `
    | Out-File $file1"_"$file2"_Comparison.txt" -Force
}
catch {
    Write-Host "There was an error"
}
```

However, as soon as I wrap the code in a function, as `compareFiles() { ... }`, when I run the same line that did work without it being included in a function, `.\Compare-Files.ps1 -file1 test1.txt -file2 test2.txt`, nothing outputs. When I add a function call in the script below the function `compareFiles`, it then prompts me for `$file1`, the fails and does not prompt me for `$file2`, as it did before, just this time my `catch` caught it.

Then, I made the `Param ()` global by placing them above the function `compareFiles`, and it worked!

Now, I need to focus on cleaning up with output a little bit. The output was as follows:

```
InputObject    SideIndicator
-----------    -------------
    test2      =>           
    1          =>           
    23         =>           
    3          =>           
    4          =>           
    5          =>           
    6          =>           
    799        =>           
    asaskjdahs =>           
    sl kasldkJ =>           
test1          <=           
1              <=           
2              <=           
3              <=           
4              <=           
5              <=           
6              <=           
7              <=           
asaskjdahs     <=           
sl kasldk      <=
```

If any of you has any advise to make the output look something like:

```
test2.txt:

InputObject    SideIndicator
-----------    -------------
    test2      =>           
    1          =>           
    23         =>           
    3          =>           
    4          =>           
    5          =>           
    6          =>           
    799        =>           
    asaskjdahs =>           
    sl kasldkJ =>

    test1.txt

    test1      <=           
    1          <=           
    2          <=           
    3          <=           
    4          <=           
    5          <=           
    6          <=           
    7          <=           
    asaskjdahs <=           
    sl kasldk  <=
```

Also, I notice that it says that `test1.txt` has different content on lines 1, 2, 3, 4, etc, but they are actually the same (`1` in `test1.txt` is the same and on the same line as `test2.txt`, for example).

Any advise for cleaning this up a bit?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: in the parameters you use $file1 and $file2, then you use $obj1 and $obj2...

Comment: also you are invoking the script, and not the function

Comment: @MickyBalladelli My apologies. I took those out and updated my question. It still does not produce any output. Ran `.\Compare-Files.ps1 -file1 "test1.txt" -file2 "test2.txt"` from the script path. Tried with and without the `| Out-File`

Comment: try invoking your function: `compareFiles -file1 "test1.txt" -file2 "test2.txt"`

Comment: you might still have an issue with those lines: `$file1 = resolve-path \.$file1`

Comment: @MickyBalladelli I updated the code yet again. I found an example on GitHub that compares MS Word files. I used that as a template in a way and updated the question. Thank you for all of your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The question keeps changing and the code exhibits a variety of unrelated problems, so it's hard to give a meaningful answer, but here are a few pointers:

- `Param (
  [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
  $file1,
  $file2
  )` only defines *`$file1`* as mandatory, not also `$file2` - each parameter needs its own `[Parameter(...)]` attribute.
- `\.$file1` and `\.$file2` don't work the way you expect to; perhaps you meant `.\$file1` and `.\$file2` to refer to files in the *current* directory, but you don't need any prefix, because `Resolve-Path` defaults to the current directory anyway.
- Tests `$file1 -eq $null` and `$file2 -eq $null` will *never* succeed, because `$file1` and `$file2`, due to having been declared `[string]` parameters, are *never* `$null`.

  - A `[string]`-typed variable in PowerShell defaults to the *empty string* rather than `$null`, and even explicitly *assigning* `$null` results in the empty string (compare that to C#, where `string` variables default to `null`, and assigning `null` is possible).
- Expanding (interpolating) variables `$file1` and `$file2` in string `"$file1_$file2_Compare.txt"` won't work, because, given that `_` is a legal character in a variable name, you must tell PowerShell where the variable names *end*, by enclosing them in `{...}`: `"${file1}_${file2}_Compare.txt"`

Comment: Sorry about the question changing all the time. I like the way you used `{}` for inserting the filename of `$file1` and `$file2`. I added `if($out -eq $null) { $out=${file1}+"_"+${file2}+"_Comparison.txt" }` and it works if there is no `-out` argument. Thank you for the knowledge.

Comment: My pleasure; the point of using `{...}` around variable names was that you could use them _inside_ of  _one_ double-quoted string, without having to use explicit string concatenation with `+`: `"${file1}_${file2}_Compare.txt"`. If there is no preexisting `$out` [parameter] variable, then yes, you can use `$out -eq $null` (better: `$null -eq $out`) in a test. But if there's a `[string]`-constrained `$out` parameter variable, you must compare to `''` (empty string) instead. Even better, use `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('out')`.